# needed requirements for asp.net mvc 3?

Tags: iis, asp.net-mvc-3, iis-7, iis-6, iis-7.5

I am just wondering what is needed to run asp.net mvc 3(hosting wise)?

```
.net 4.0 - I read is needed
iis 6 - can you use this? (not planning to use it but just want to know)
iis 7 - can you use this
iis 7.5 - pretty sure you can use this to run your asp.net mvc 3 site.
```

I am just trying to figure out what is the lowest requirements needed to run asp.net mvc 3(razor).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> iis 6 - can you use this?

Yes, you can.

> iis 7 - can you use this

Of course.

> iis 7.5 - pretty sure you can use this to run your asp.net mvc 3 site.

Absolutely.

.NET 4.0 and ASP.NET MVC 3 are the most important pre-requisites to be installed on the server. So anything ranging from Win 2003 (IIS 6.0) to Win 2008 R2 (IIS 7.5) will work assuming you install those two components.

There's one caveat though with IIS 6.0 and it is about [extensionless routes](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/26/asp.net-mvc-on-iis-6-walkthrough.aspx). If you want those you will need to associate the ASP.NET ISAPI filter to all requests.

Comment: Really so basically the only real requirement change from asp.net mvc 2 to 3 is you need to use .net 4 then?

Comment: @chobo2, absolutely. And of course you need ASP.NET MVC 3 to be installed as well which requires .NET 4.0. So first install .NET 4.0 and then ASP.NET MVC 3 and you are ready to ship.

Comment: @ Darin Dimitrov  - Ok cool then I think I can go ahead and propose asp.net mvc 3 instead of using 2.0

Comment: @chobo2, go ahead => propose it. It's definitely better than ASP.NET MVC 2.0 and it's also gonna work in the same environment as ASP.NET MVC 2.0.

Comment: Yep I been using asp.net mvc 3.0 since like 3 days after it's official release on personal projects and love it :)

Answer (score 1):

To add some more information to this question  - if you want to deploy everything with a razor site to run on IIS (for instance if you are with a hosting provider) you can check out Phil Haacks posting on this for the right click "Add Deployable Assemblies" option.

[Bin Deploying ASP.Net MVC 3](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/05/25/bin-deploying-asp-net-mvc-3.aspx)