# ASP.NET MVC 3 Requirements

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Will ASP.NET MVC 3 run on Windows Server 2008 R2 Core? I've done some searching and can't seem to find this information.

Thanks

Comment: Deleted my answer because I misread your question. Sorry about that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [needed requirements for asp.net mvc 3?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6285952/needed-requirements-for-asp-net-mvc-3)

Comment: The requirements aren't so much the version of Windows, but other factors.

Comment: You need IIS, .Net 4 and the MVC installer run on the server, I dont see any reason why you couldnt run this on server core having said that ive never done it

Comment: According to http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753802(v=ws.10).aspx it supports Web Server (including a subset of ASP.NET). Based on some to the additional features you can install (linked from the url) it looks very limited and I would assume no to MVC3

Comment: thanks all. @tawman, if you make that as an answer i would accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just set up a Windows Server 2008 R2 in Server Core configuration. I installed MVC3 using the standard installer:

```
.\AspNetMVC3Setup.exe /q /log C:\mvc3setup.htm
```

This installed successfully and **a sample MVC3 site works just fine**.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Server Core Installation Option Getting Started Guide](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753802%28v=ws.10%29.aspx), Windows Server 2008 R2 Core supports Web Server (including a subset of ASP.NET). Based on some to the additional features you can install [(optional features)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee441253%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) it looks very limited.

The red flags that stand out for me on the optional features are:

- Subset of .NET Framework 3.0 and 3.5
- Subset of .NET Framework 2.0

Based on the documentation, I come to the conclusion that running MVC3 would be very difficult and not possible.